# Data Loss when Switching media server from Server to Desktop

Tags: software-installation

I have a server running Ubuntu Server through command line, but I am not good with the command line. A friend of mine always kept it up to speed on the difficult tasks and errors, and I could basically do the simple stuff only, such as copy files, delete folders, and update.

Now the sad fact is my friend passed away too young, and besides the obvious grief I am left with a server I can not maintain properly. I am too much of a novice to try and pick it up from scratch right now, but I do have 7.5 Tb of data on the machine apart from the system drive.

Can I do a wipe of the system drive, install ubuntu desktop and start using that as a more user friendly type mediaserver? Or would the uninstallation of the ubuntu server cause any problems with my (seperately stored) data downloaded by the server.

Please understand my level, i am willing to learn but I am a bit out of place amoung the experts. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reinstall anything. Just installing the `ubuntu-desktop` package (if you like unity) or any other of the `*-desktop` packages should be enough.